# How access session factory (dataSource) in alfresco?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, alfresco

Working with common spring application I can define dataSource or Hibernate session factory as bean and then simply autowire them. like that:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

or

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

For now I want to create some tables and store them in alfresco. How get `dataSource` or `sessionFactory` (if alfresco uses hibernate) which is pointed to alfresco database?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I try your solution this week and post a result.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the `dataSource` bean defined in [core-services-context.xml](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/core-services-context.xml):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.alfresco.config.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultObject">
        <ref bean="defaultDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

using `your-config-context.xml`, for example [ibatis-context.xml](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml):

```
<bean id="repoSqlSessionFactory" class="org.alfresco.ibatis.HierarchicalSqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoader" ref="dialectResourceLoader"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:alfresco/ibatis/alfresco-SqlMapConfig.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Be aware that:

> Alfresco incorporates Hibernate and iBATIS open source database
>   abstraction layers to allow it to be ported to a number of different
>   database management systems.

so, it is preferred to use [MyBatis-Spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/) and [`org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate`](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html), for example [`org.alfresco.repo.domain.audit.ibatis.AuditDAOImpl.java`](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/domain/audit/ibatis/AuditDAOImpl.java):

```
<bean id="auditSqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="repoSqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="auditDAO" class="org.alfresco.repo.domain.audit.ibatis.AuditDAOImpl">
    <property name="sqlSessionTemplate" ref="auditSqlSessionTemplate"/>
    <property name="contentService" ref="contentService"/>
    <property name="contentDataDAO" ref="contentDataDAO"/>
    <property name="propertyValueDAO" ref="propertyValueDAO"/>
</bean>
```

This [Alfresco 5 and Spring tutorial](http://alfrescoblog.com/2015/09/03/alfresco-5-and-spring-tutorial/#) might be helpful for you.